# Vuejs moving data between multiple components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a parent component with two children components that I need data to move between. I can get emitted data from one child (multiselect.vue) to the parent, but cannot get it to then move into the other child component (render.vue). I suspect it has something to with v-model. Below is a simplifed version.

Parent component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <multiSelect v-model="content" />
    <renderSplashPage :content="render" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import multiSelect from '@/utils/multiSelect'
import render from '@/components/Render'

export default {
  components: {
    multiSelect,
    render,
  },
    name: 'somename',
  data(){
    return{
      content: {},
      render: {}
    }
  },
  watch: {
    'content': function(val) {
      this.render = val;
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

How can I get the emitted data to be 'watched' and 'picked up' by the 'render' component?

Comment: Is `multiselect.vue` modifying the data in anyway? Is that modified data what you need to pass to `render.vue`?

Comment: Are you sure the watch is called? have you logged the value? If the response is YES for both, then you have problems with the fact that vue data objects are not deeply reactive. So you shouldn't change the reference of an object like that .

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think its because vuejs objects not being deeply reactive is my problem here. I'm going to re-work it and see if I can sort it out that way.

Answer (score 3):

`render` is a **reserved** name (i.e., the internal [`render` function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) cannot be overwritten), and for some reason, Vue silently ignores attempts to modify it.

Rename your property (e.g., to "myRender"), and you should see reactivity. If `myRender` is always equal to `content`, you could actually just replace it with `content` in your binding:

```
<multiselect v-model="content" :options="options" />
<render :content="content" />
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/5k4qo2r9mn)

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I tried simplifying it to paste here (didn't know 'render' was reserved). In my actual code its named differently. I'll keep that in mind in the future, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used a variation of this here to solve my issue:

```
this.someObject = Object.assign({}, this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })
```

Taken from here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Are you still using the watcher? I would really suggest just using the same variable that you have in the select's v-model and making sure that that is properly reactive. Watchers only exist for really specific cases where other Vue functionalities won't cover it, you should consider using the reactive variable instead if you haven't already.